# Restrict Pattern Matching to Subset of Constructors

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, data-kinds

Say I have the following:

```
data Type
  = StringType
  | IntType
  | FloatType

data Op
  = Add Type
  | Subtract Type
```

I'd like to constrain the possible types under `Subtract`, such that it only allows for int or float. In other words,

```
patternMatch :: Op -> ()
patternMatch (Add StringType) = ()
patternMatch (Add IntType) = ()
patternMatch (Add FloatType) = ()
patternMatch (Subtract IntType) = ()
patternMatch (Subtract FloatType) = ()
```

Should be an exhaustive pattern match.

One way of doing this is to introduce separate datatypes for each operation, where it only has the allowed subtypes:

```
newtype StringType = StringType
newtype IntType = IntType
newtype FloatType = FloatType

data Addable = AddableString StringType | AddableInt IntType | AddableFloat FloatType

data Subtractable = SubtractableInt IntType | SubtractableFloat FloatType

data Op = Add Addable | Subtract Subtractable
```

However, this makes things a lot more verbose, as we have to create a new constructor name for each category. Is there a way to 'restrict' the possible constructors within a type without making an explicit subset?
Would this shorter with the use of `DataKinds`? I'm a bit unsure as to how to make it more concise than just specifying new data for each constraint.

This question is an extension of my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720058/datakind-unions), where I asked about datakind unions. There were lots of good suggestions there, but unfortunately the unions don't work when pattern matching; the compiler will still complain that the patterns are not exhaustive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a GADT with `DataKinds` is one approach that may work, depending on your use case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- The “group” of a type
data TypeGroup = NonNumeric | Numeric

-- A type indexed by whether it’s numeric
data Type (g :: TypeGroup) where
  StringType :: Type 'NonNumeric
  IntType :: Type 'Numeric
  FloatType :: Type 'Numeric

data Op where
  Add :: Type a -> Op
  Subtract :: Type 'Numeric -> Op
```

Note that `Add` works on either `'Numeric` or `'NonNumeric` `Type`s because of the (existentially quantified) type variable `a`.

Now this will work:

```
patternMatch :: Op -> ()
patternMatch (Add StringType) = ()
patternMatch (Add IntType) = ()
patternMatch (Add FloatType) = ()
patternMatch (Subtract IntType) = ()
patternMatch (Subtract FloatType) = ()
```

But adding this will fail:

```
patternMatch (Subtract StringType) = ()
```

With a warning about inaccessible code: `Couldn't match type ‘'Numeric’ with ‘'NonNumeric’`.

If you need to add more type groupings, you may prefer to introduce type families to classify types instead, e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

-- An un-indexed type
data TypeTag = StringTag | IntTag | FloatTag

-- A type indexed with a tag we can dispatch on
data Type (t :: TypeTag) where
  StringType :: Type StringTag
  IntType :: Type IntTag
  FloatType :: Type FloatTag

-- Classify a type as numeric
type family IsNumeric' (t :: TypeTag) :: Bool where
  IsNumeric' 'StringTag = 'False
  IsNumeric' 'IntTag = 'True
  IsNumeric' 'FloatTag = 'True

-- A convenience synonym for the constraint
type IsNumeric t = (IsNumeric' t ~ 'True)

data Op where
  Add :: Type t -> Op
  Subtract :: IsNumeric t => Type t -> Op
```

This will produce the (slightly less descriptive) warning `Couldn't match type ‘'True’ with ‘'False’` if you add the redundant pattern.

When working with GADTs you will often want existentials and `RankNTypes` in order to work with runtime information; for that, patterns like these may prove useful:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

-- Hide the type-level tag of a type
data SomeType where
  SomeType :: Type t -> SomeType

-- An unknown type, but that is known to be numeric
data SomeNumericType where
  SomeNumericType :: IsNumeric t => Type t -> SomeNumericType

parseType :: String -> Maybe SomeType
parseType "String" = Just (SomeType StringType)
parseType "Int" = Just (SomeType IntType)
parseType "Float" = Just (SomeType FloatType)
parseType _ = Nothing

-- Unpack the hidden tag within a function
withSomeType :: SomeType -> (forall t. Type t -> r) -> r
withSomeType (SomeType t) k = k t
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution works but it might not be very practical in the end. I'm using extensible variants from the [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record) package.

We define our types like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeApplications #-}
import           GHC.Generics
import           Data.RBR

data Ty
  = StringTy ()
  | IntTy ()
  | FloatTy ()
  deriving (Show,Generic)
instance ToVariant Ty

type ShrunkTy = Variant I (Delete "StringTy" () (VariantCode Ty))

data Op
  = Add Ty
  | Subtract ShrunkTy
```

Those annoying `()` parameters are there to overcome a [limitation](https://github.com/danidiaz/red-black-record/issues/7) of red-black-record; currently there are no instances of [`ToVariant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:ToVariant) for sum types without constructor arguments.

Basically, we are removing the `StringTy` constructor from the [`VariantCode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:VariantCode) using the [`Delete`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:Deletable) type family, and defining a [`Variant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:Variant) with the reduced set of constructors.

We can then use the type like this:

```
foo :: Op -> String
foo op = 
    case op of
        Add ty -> 
            show "add" ++ show ty
        Subtract ty -> 
            let cases = addCaseI @"IntTy"   show
                      . addCaseI @"FloatTy" show
                      $ unit
            in  show "add" ++ eliminateSubset cases ty
```

`Variant`s are [eliminated](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:eliminateSubset) using a [`Record`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:Record) of handlers, constructed using the [`addCaseI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:addCaseI) function. [`unit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:unit) is the empty `Record`. If the `Record` doesn't cover all cases that will result in a (pretty inscrutable) type error.

---

The disadvantages with this solution are:

- Different syntax for handling the shrunk type.
- Worse type errors.
- Slower at runtime, not as efficient as native sum types.
- The usual bane of extensible record libraries: [very slow](https://github.com/danidiaz/red-black-record/issues/12) compilation times for large types.

Other extensible record libraries ([vinyl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl) + [vinyl-generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-generics), perhaps) might offer better ergonomics.